# Controller inside a folder inside a folder not working (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been doing pretty good with codeigniter but now I've hit a little snag. Instead of having everything in one controller file, I want to redistribute it throughout many files inside a sub-folder. For instance:

**localhost/folderA/folderB/controllerFile**

This way folder B replaces the home file for the controller and all the files can be dispersed inside this new folder since there's no need to have 10 different controller functions inside a single file (makes it large you know).

In routes I added a new line to

**$route['folderA/folderB/(:any)/'] = 'folderA/folderB';**

I don't even think it's even necessary to add a route but it wasn't working, always getting a 404 page no matter what. Now, the very same code for the controller works perfectly well if I bring it back by a folder. This means that **/folderA/folderB/controllerFile** works in **/folderA/controllerFile** without worries.

My objective is not to resort to moving these files up a directory but to keep the structure the same as it once was. Has anyone gone mad over something like this? I'd imagine so... lol

Thanks for reading!

**Edit: For clarification this is what's going on:**

```
  /application/controllers/file.php (OK)
  /application/controllers/folderA/file.php (OK)
  /application/controllers/folderA/folderB/file.php (This does not work)
```

I could do /application/controllers/folderA/file.php and have all of the functions inside of it so it works as followed:

```
localhost/folderA/file
localhost/folderA/file/functionb
localhost/folderA/file/functionc
```

But this makes the file rather unnecessarily large when the same result could be done using sub-sub directories. Makes sense?

Comment: [As per the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories), you can have subdirectories as long as all controllers & subdirectories containing controllers go inside of the `controllers` directory.  Alternatively, using the `routes` configuration file, you can construct the URL to look like whatever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I figured out the solution using **routes**. While I don't understand exactly why codeigniter doesn't allow a 3-level folder, what I ended up doing is creating a new folder inside **/application/controllers/test/** and within that folder I had my **test.php** file.

Then I went back to the routes configuration file and added the following line:

```
$route['foldera/testPage/testing'] = 'test/test';
```

What this effectively does is that when you direct your browser to the page

```
http://localhost/foldera/testPage/testing
```

It will treat that page as found in /application/controllers/test/test.php

It's basically giving it an alias. However if you go to localhost/test/test it will have no issues with this and treat it the exact same as foldera/testPage/testing.php In order to resolve this little issue, simply add another line to the routes config file

```
$route['test/test'] = 'notfound'; // Your 404 page controller
```

Now the only way to access that folder is directly from the URL that you want. Ta-da!

Comment: there are things that you can do, but i would strongly suggest not doing. and one of them is naming folders and the files inside them the same name. especially for controllers and models. and while i'm rattling on don't name models the same name as controllers. conversely it can help to name folders that contain views, or view files, the same or similar to the controllers calling them. thats ok because you only load views - you never call methods from them.

Comment: What are you really gaining here?  In other words, you can use routes to achieve the **same** URL while **not** having your actual controller file buried three levels deep.

Comment: hey on the flip side i do this as well. i have an application where there are a few controllers 'buried' under two folders. same for models. i think for larger applications its much better to have folders to keep things separate. a good folder structure can help make things easier to understand.

Comment: The difference now is that instead of having a controller file inside a sub-folder that has 10 different web page functions say function blogroll, function comments, function recent etc... (All in one page) they are spaced out in their own files but having it in a subfolder inside a folder didn't quite work with codeigniter. Check out the edits I made to the OP for clarification but it works exactly as I want it :)

Comment: *"I don't understand exactly why codeigniter doesn't allow a 3-level folder"* ~ I guess the developers at CodeIgniter simply decided that one subdirectory level for controllers is adequate for most users in their audience.   Deeper URL structures can be achieved with `routes.php`.

Answer (score 5):

> Instead of having everything in one controller file, I want to redistribute it throughout many files inside a sub-folder. ... all the files can be dispersed inside this new folder since there's no need to have 10 different controller functions inside a single file.

You can already put functions into multiple controller files under one directory called `controllers`.  There was never a requirement to put all functions into one controller file.

By default, all controllers are stored in the `controllers` directory...

```
/application/controllers/
```

Example:

```
/application/controllers/Users.php
/application/controllers/Auth.php
/application/controllers/Etc.php
```

> I don't even think it's even necessary to add a route but it wasn't working, always getting a 404 page no matter what.

If you want to use subdirectories for controllers, then these subdirectories **must** be contained within the `controllers` directory and you need to follow the documentation.

```
/application/controllers/subfolderA/
/application/controllers/subfolderB/
```

[As per the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories):

> If you are building a large application you might want to hierarchically organize or structure your controllers into sub-directories. CodeIgniter permits you to do this.
>
> Simply create sub-directories under the main `application/controllers/` one and place your controller classes within them.
>
> When using this feature the first segment of your URI must specify the folder.
>
> Each of your sub-directories may contain a default controller which will be called if the URL contains only the sub-directory.  Simply put a controller in there that matches the name of your `default_controller` as specified in your `application/config/routes.php` file.
>
> CodeIgniter also permits you to remap your URIs using its [URI Routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) feature.

---

**EDIT**:

> I could do `/application/controllers/folderA/file.php` and have all of the functions inside of it so it works as followed:

```
localhost/folderA/file
localhost/folderA/file/functionb
localhost/folderA/file/functionc
```

> But **this makes the file rather unnecessarily large** when the same result could be done using sub-sub directories. Makes sense?

**Why do you keep talking about a "single large file"?**  You can break your functions up into as many controller files as you wish without the need of any subdirectories...

```
/application/controllers/Users.php
/application/controllers/Auth.php
/application/controllers/Etc.php
```

Respectively accessed via URL as

```
/users/function_foo
/auth/function_bar
/etc/function_foobar
```

Then using `routes.php`, you can achieve whatever complex URL you wish...

```
$route['foldera/testPage/testing'] = 'users/function_foo';
```

However, if you want to use a subdirectory within the `controllers` directory...

```
/application/controllers/subdirectory/Controller_a.php
```

Accessed via URL as...

```
/subdirectory/controller_a/some_function
```

Can be re-routed as *literally anything you want*...

```
$route['foo/bar/anything/here/tester/foobar'] = 'subdirectory/controller_a/some_function';
```

Comment: Thanks for that and by your definition I have no problem since I've been doing /application/controllers/subfolderA/ etc...  What I mean is that I am trying to get /application/controllers/subfolderA/subofasubfolder/controllerfile.php. Does that make sense?

Comment: @phpvillain, I don't think CodeIgniter will work like that:  the documentation only describes the **first** segment as representing the subfolder.  Your OP mentions 10 different controllers or functions; IMO, having more than one level is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up figuring a way to do it "outside the box". I posted the answer :) Thanks for your help, I couldn't understand why you listed different folders and then it dawned on me.

Comment: @phpvillain, if you're just trying to achieve a certain URL, then you do not need to worry about burying your controller files in subdirectories.  You can just create the complex URL with the `routes.php` file and leave your 10 controllers in the controller folder's root.